# how can I make a correct question using word free

Tags: sentence-construction

How can I ask someone whether he/she is free or not or they have time to answer me?

How can I ask this question formally?

Answer (score 1):

In most situations, simply asking "Are you free?" works quite well. If the person seems to be busy but your question is urgent, you can say

> Can you spare a minute to...

If somebody looks very busy, you can say

> Sorry to bother you, but...